# How to navigate to UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I just want to navigate to a UIWebview. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I have written this code :

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"LoginUrl"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Attile if you take the time to improve posts please watch your own grammar. In English, "i" should be capital "I".

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I only reviewed the title and the source code. The pronoun 'I' was the part of the original question, it's not added by me. I guess we were editing the post with Rui Jarimba at the same time and this caused the inconsistency in the edit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a instance of UIWebView. 
Then you can tell the WebView to load the URL Request via

```
[yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```